# convert string to Object in vue using Json.parse

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I want to transform the the input value from the input element  into an Object

using `Json.parse()` to convert the `internData` value does not convert the string to an Object

doing the same operation in the browser console returns the correct outcome.

```
let data = "[1,2,3,4]";

JSON.parse(datas)
(4) [1, 2, 3, 4]

typeof z
'object'
```

What am I missing here ?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      datatype: "foo",
      internData: "[1, 2, 3]",
    };
  },

  methods: {
    transformData() {
      //
      //
      JSON.parse(this.internData);

     
      //  this.internData.push(12);

      return this.internData;
    },
    whatFormat(){
      console.log(typeof this.internData)
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <h5> {{ data }}</h5>
     
       <input v-model="internData" @input="onInputme" />
      
       <button type="button" @click="transformData">click to transform</button>
   <button type="button" @click="whatFormat">what data type</button>
    
   
    
    </div>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `transformData() {
 return JSON.parse(this.internData);
},`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue that you currently have is that you are not updating the `internData` from the `transformData` function youe should reassign `internData` with JSON parsed format of same inside the function just like below

```
transformData() {
  this.internData = JSON.parse(this.internData);
}
```

**OR**

You could make `transformData` as a computed property and watch for the type of `transformData`. Here you can get rid of the click event to parse the data.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      datatype: "foo",
      internData: "[1, 2, 3]",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    whatFormat() {
      console.log(this.transformData);
      console.log(typeof this.transformData);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    transformData: function () {
      return JSON.parse(this.internData)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="internData" />
  <button type="button" @click="whatFormat">what data type</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `transformData` function transforms the string, but the newly created object is not assigned to the internData property.

This should do the trick:

```js
transformData() {
  this.internData = JSON.parse(this.internData);
},
```